# my reference doesn't start in order from [1] but it starts from [2]

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, thesis

i am writing my thesis in latex,
my problem with the first reference .its start from [2] not from[1],all the rest of the thesis reference's is correct order.i didn't understand where is the problem.
\backmattermodel
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{sample}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\clearemptydoublepage
\end{document}
the sample is my reference file.

it is happen to me before when i wrote a article ,it was there a  \bibitem in the article for that it was starting from [2] ,but this time i tried to search any  \bibitem ,i didn't find any  one.
i want to put my code here but ,it is very long. thanks

Comment: you give very few clues but do you mean that the actual list at the end has no entry `[1]` ? that would be very weird, or do you mean that the first `\cite` in the text produces `[2]` the usual reason for that is a `\cite` in a caption and appeared in the list of figures in the front matter as `[1]`

Comment: I mean that the first \cite in the text produces [2],and figure list is like that 1.1 and 1.2 ..etc

Comment: you are right ,i find one figure in chapter 2 has \cite ,so i delete the \cite and it working.thank you very much.but if i want to keep the cite in caption of the figure how i can start my reference from [1] in the text produces

Comment: This is a duplicate (I'll find the link) but use `\caption[caption without the \cite for list of figures]{full caption with \cite}`

Comment: yes, its working thank you very much.